# Need to create a slicer in Power BI based on Groups of values in a column. Some values belong to multiple groups

Tags: powerbi

I have a main table of data and visuals based on this data (many other columns but this is the basic idea)

| Item | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Thing1 | Red |
| Thing2 | Orange |
| Thing3 | Yellow |
| Thing4 | Orange |
| Thing5 | Blue |
| Thing6 | Yellow |
| Thing7 | Green |

The Values belong to multiple Groups, and there is overlap between them (Orange in this example).

Group1 - Red, Orange, Yellow

Group2 - Orange, Blue, Green

I want to create a slicer where the options are "Group1" and "Group2" to filter the lines with values in that group. Choosing Group1 will show me Thing1, Thing2, Thing3, Thing4, Thing6 in the visuals and Group2 will show me Thing2, Thing4, Thing5, Thing7.

I have tried creating new tables as below to join the data but Power BI will not allow me to create a many-to-many relationship to Values in the main table.

Slicer Table

| Group |
| --- |
| Group1 |
| Group2 |

Group-Value

| Group | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Group1 | Red |
| Group1 | Orange |
| Group1 | Yellow |
| Group2 | Orange |
| Group2 | Blue |
| Group2 | Green |

I have also tried creating measures using SELECTEDVALUE in DAX but I don't know if that is a viable option, as it doesn't seem to do what I want.

Comment: Yes, you may want to keep your slicer table unrelated to the main/fact table, and calculate a measure filtering according to the selectedvalue of that slicer table.